# transport optimization R studio

Tags: r, matrix, linear-programming, transport

I'm trying to set up a linear program on how a commodity will move between states. I'm working with R studio, using the lpSolve package. I'm very new to R so excuse the basic language! But I've looked through the help files and can't seem to work out what the problem is.

States are both "suppliers" (*m*) and "demanders" (*n*). I want a matrix of the units transported, which means the diagonal elements of my matrix will be 0. Demand must equal supply, and demand is met first by the states own supply, followed by excess supply from other states. My demand and supply totals are equal. The objective function is the cost matrix - I think this is just a typical "transport problem". There are 5 states, and for ease below I've just given the data for "excess supply" and "unmet demand" i.e. not including the constraint for supply must equal demand. There are just two sets of constraints for equal to supply/demand totals.

I've found the following code in *Modeling and Solving Linear Programming with R* by Sallan et al.

```
obj.fun <- c(0, 1706.7028, 1916.6580, 2136.8103, 2022.6844, 1700.9534, 0, 
 1975.2873, 2274.0058, 1351.2115, 1909.6172, 1973.9959, 0, 310.3474, 
 851.0575, 2129.6639, 2272.6088, 310.2418, 0, 1101.0733, 2013.8803, 
 1348.1568, 849.2942, 1099.4156, 0)
 m <- 5
 n <- 5
 constr <- matrix (0 , n +m , n*m )
 for(i in 1:m){ 
 for(j in 1:n){ 
    constr[i, n*(i-1) + j] <- 1
   constr[m+j, n*(i-1) + j] <- 1
   }
   }

 constr.dir <- c(rep("=",m ), rep("=", n))
   rhs <- c(0, 0, 0, 528534585, 5181690936, 2446322302, 412720974, 
  2851182245, 0 , 0)

   prod.trans <- lp ("min", obj.fun, constr, constr.dir, rhs,
                   compute.sens = TRUE )
  prod.trans$obj.val
  sol<-matrix (prod.trans$solution, m, n, byrow=TRUE)
  prod.trans$duals
```

However, when I run it, I just get a matrix of zeros:

```
> prod.trans$obj.val
> NULL 
> sol<-matrix (prod.trans$solution, m, n, byrow=TRUE)
> prod.trans$duals
> [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I'm assuming it's either that I can't have diagonal elements as 0 in the matrix?

Any advice is greatly appreciated - even just pointing me in the direction of where to get some help!

Thanks!
F

Answer (score 2):

1. Divide `rhs` by 1e9. This scaling will help keep numbers in a normal range. You can interpret this as a change of units (say from grams to kilotons).
2. Replace `prod.trans$obj.val` by `prod.trans$objval`

You will see:

```
> prod.trans$objval
[1] 7619.598
> sol<-matrix (prod.trans$solution, m, n, byrow=TRUE)
> prod.trans$duals
 [1] -1164.5861  -498.8626     0.0000   310.2418   849.2942  1164.5861   498.8626     0.0000  -310.2418  -849.2942
[11]     0.0000  2372.4263  3081.2441  3611.6382  4036.5647  1035.2299     0.0000  2474.1499  3083.1102  2699.3683
[21]   745.0311  1475.1333     0.0000   620.5892  1700.3517   654.8360  1463.5044     0.0000     0.0000  1640.1257
[31]     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000   560.3632     0.0000
>
```

Comment: Hi there - I've just come back to this analysis after some time off, and I've come into a couple more issues. The actual analysis involves a 35:35 matrix, not 5. I've checked with 5 and the code works, but when I run with 35 I get 0 again. Is it possible for the model to not find an optimal solution, or would this be another coding issue? The total for supply and demand don't quite match, so I wondered if it could be that.

Comment: Inspect the result and check it is not infeasible. The model as stated assumes this is a balanced transportation problem. You can always make things balanced by adding dummy nodes.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else comes across such a transport problem as well:

There is a very handy built-in function in lpSolve called **lp.transport**, which does the same thing as the solution with **lp** above, but directly takes a cost matrix and separate constraint vectors for rows and columns as arguments.

```
# set up the matrix of transport costs
m <- 5
n <- 5
cost_mat <- matrix(c(0, 1706.7028, 1916.6580, 2136.8103, 2022.6844, 1700.9534, 0, 
                     1975.2873, 2274.0058, 1351.2115, 1909.6172, 1973.9959, 0, 310.3474, 
                     851.0575, 2129.6639, 2272.6088, 310.2418, 0, 1101.0733, 2013.8803, 
                     1348.1568, 849.2942, 1099.4156, 0),
                   nrow = m, ncol = n, byrow = TRUE)

# constraints for rows and columns, devided by 1e9
row_rhs <- c(0, 0, 0, 528534585, 5181690936)/1e9
col_rhs <- c(2446322302, 412720974, 2851182245, 0 , 0)/1e9

# solve
prod_trans <- lp.transport(cost.mat = cost_mat, direction = "min", row.signs = rep("=", m), row.rhs = row_rhs,  col.signs = rep("=", m), col.rhs = col_rhs, compute.sens = TRUE, integers = NULL)
```

This yields the same result as [Erwin's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5625534/erwin-kalvelagen) solution.

```
> prod_trans
Success: the objective function is 7619.598 

> prod_trans$solution
         [,1]     [,2]      [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000    0    0
[2,] 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000    0    0
[3,] 0.000000 0.000000 0.0000000    0    0
[4,] 0.000000 0.000000 0.5285346    0    0
[5,] 2.446322 0.412721 2.3226477    0    0

> prod_trans$duals 
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] -1164.586 -498.8626    0.0000  310.2418  849.2942
[2,]  1164.586  498.8626    0.0000 -310.2418 -849.2942
[3,]     0.000 1035.2299  745.0311  654.8360    0.0000
[4,]  2372.426    0.0000 1475.1333 1463.5044    0.0000
[5,]  3081.244 2474.1499    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000
```